# Karate tests: How to get list of specific field from response object

Tags: karate

Suppose my response object is of form:

```
[
{ id:"id1",
name: "name1"
},
{ id:"id2",
name: "name2"
},
{ id:"id3",
name: "name3"
}
]
```

And i want to only validate on Ids received , how do i extract that from response?

I have tried

```
        * def filt = function(x){ return x.id }
        * def items = get response[*]
        * def ids = karate.filter(items, filt)
```

But this gives me empty array for Ids

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this resolved using

```
    * def items = get response[*]
    * def ids = $items[*].id
```

Comment: one line is enough: `* def ids = $[*].id`